# Converting C code to Java:Pointers

Tags: java, c

I know we cannot access address of an Object safely in Java and we should never try to do something like this. But i need to convert this C code to Java. Value is always of size `8 bits`. The C code is like this:

```
void merge(int value,unsigned short* outp, int x,int y, int width)
{
    unsigned char *outc;
    outc=(unsigned char *) outp + y*width +x;
    *outc=value;
}
```

To convert it into Java I have converted `unsigned short* outp` to `short outp[]` and `unsigned char* outc` to `short outc[]`. Then i can assign values in parts. But the problem i am facing is that when this function is called in a loop by some other function the width is incremented each time and only one byte is assigned to a particular cell..

I tried this Java code:

```
void merge(int value, int outp[], int x, int y, int width)
{

if(outp[y*width + x] >0)
   {    
        outp[y*width+x]=outp[y*width+x]<<8 +value;
   }
   else
   {
        outp[y*width+x]=value;
   }
}
```

How can i do this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't do this. This seriously effects the readability. Try to understand the logic and rewrite the same in Java. Add comments as well, the person next to you will bless you.

Comment: @questzen sorry but i didn't understand what not to do..

Comment: one word 'readability'. The next person would have to go through the same hurdles to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

It is not "possible" in java that does not have pointers. It has references that are irrelevant for primitive type like `char`.

So, in java we typically use method that returns value instead of returning the value via pointer like C programmers do:

```
char merge(int value,int x,int y, int width) {
    char outchar;
    /// your code...
    return outchar;
}
```

Comment: But this code is part of a very big project,i have written some 10000 lines of Java code. I just need to write this function to make my code work.

Comment: -1, for giving advice that is completely unrelated to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code should do. To me it looks like it only sets the lower byte of a short to the given value and the shift in your java code seems out of place. Since you for some reason replaced short[] with int[] i don't know if the following will help:

```
void merge(int value,short[] outp, int x,int y, int width){
   int address =  y*width +x;
   short temp = outp[address];
   temp &= 0xFF00;//keep the high order bits of the old value
   temp |= (short)(value & 0x00FF);//set the low order bits
   outp[address] = temp;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your C code looks like pointer arithmetic to find the address of a cell at a particular location in a grid, then set the value at that location.

For your Java code I would recommend a completely different approach.
What data structure does your calling code use for the grid?
You could use a class which models the grid, and includes a setValue(x,y) method. How the class models the grid internally is up to you - it could use a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

As a C programmer who tried to use Java for a project, I can certainly identify with your woes.

To resolve your problem, I would rather try to access your 2D data a 1D Java bytearray.

This will make it trivial to access the (row * col) byte and you will spare the need for this wrapper code (which will be very costly in a loop).

Whether you will allocate the array from Java or from C depends on your project but JNI calls make both solutions possible.

Good luck!